# How to bind elements of a MultiCheckbox to an Object in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, checkboxlist, zend-form2, zend-form-collection

I'm using nested [`Zend\Form\Fieldset`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Fieldset.php)s and [**`Zend\Form\Collection`s**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html), that provide an extremely comfortable way to map complex object structures to the form, in order to get a complete object (ready to be saved) from the form input.

The element I want to add now to my form should represent a list of possible protocols. In the database it's a simple table with columns `id` and `name` and the objects' structure can be described like `Endpoint has Protocol[]`. I defined a `MultiCheckbox` (s. below), but I have no idea, how to bind this element to a `Protocol` prototype. For a `Fieldset` it works via [`Fieldset\setObject(...)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Fieldset.php#L446).

**How to get the form processing mechanism of `Zend\Form` creating objects from checkboxes?**

---

**Code so far:**

**`EndpointFieldset.php`**

```
// namespace ...;
// use ....;
class EndpointFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    // ...
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'multi_checkbox',
                'name' => 'protocols',
                'options' => [
                    'label' => _('protocols'),
                    'label_attributes' => [
                        'class' => 'col-md-1 protocol-field'
                    ],
                    'value_options' => $this->getValueOptions(),
                    'selected' => static::PROTOCOLS_DUMMY_VALUE
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
    // ...
    protected function getValueOptions()
    {
        $valueOptions = [];
        foreach (Protocol::PROTOCOLS as $key => $value) {
            $valueOptions[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }
        return $valueOptions;
    }
}
```

**`myform.phml`**

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox;
echo $this->formMultiCheckbox($myFieldset->get('protocols'), FormMultiCheckbox::LABEL_PREPEND);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround for the saving of a new entry: I simply complete the object provided by the form manually and make `Protocol` objects from the `MultiCheckBox` values. But when I pass complete object to the update form (in order to edit an existing entry), I get a notice and the checkboxes don't get built:

> Notice: Object of class My\DataObject\Protocol could not be converted to int in /var/www/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php on line 202

My interpretation of this is, that the `MultiCheckBox` expects an array with values as primitive types (e.g. `int`). Instead it gets an array with `Protocol` objects and tries to use its values for `in_array(...)` -- and that cannot work.

Comment: I'm seeing this same error in ZF3 with Doctrine2.  Single-stepping through everything, the Doctrine\Hydrator is setting the 'value' attribute on the MultiCheckbox (not value_options) to an array of my entities.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I know some people recommend against using bind and just do hydration of the object and/or form manually in the controller.  Maybe because this is such a pain to figure out.